# How can I create a JUnit test that runs until a certain condition is met?

Tags: java, testing, junit4

I have a simple java snake game. I'm trying to test what happens when I press a lot of keys in a short interval.
Snake is my frame and Board is the JPanel where everything happens.

```
  boolean stop=false;
  Snake snake= new Snake();

  KeyEvent key_right = new KeyEvent(snake.board, KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, System.currentTimeMillis(), 0, KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT,'Z');
  KeyEvent key_up = new KeyEvent(snake.board, KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, System.currentTimeMillis(), 0, KeyEvent.VK_UP,'Z');
  KeyEvent key_down = new KeyEvent(snake.board, KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, System.currentTimeMillis(), 0, KeyEvent.VK_DOWN,'Z');
  KeyEvent key_left = new KeyEvent(snake.board, KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, System.currentTimeMillis(), 0, KeyEvent.VK_LEFT,'Z');
  KeyEvent vect[]={key_right,key_down,key_left,key_up};
  int i=0,nr=0;
  Timer timer = new Timer();
@Test 
public void StresTaste() {

    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(!stop){

        snake.board.getKeyListeners()[0].keyPressed(vect[i]);
        System.out.println(nr);
        i++;nr++;
        if(i==3) i=0;
        if(nr==200){stop=true;}
        }





    }
    }, 1, 1);        

}
```

I create an array of keyEvents and loop over it using the i variable. I pass them to the keyListener of the JPanel.
Everything works fine.. but it stops at something over one hundred...not the same value everytime.
Please help. Is this even possible to implement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A timer is a daemon thread, i.e. when one of them is around, that won't stop the VM from stopping.

So what happens is that you start the tests, create the timer and then stop the VM (because there are no more JUnit tests). The timer gets to process a couple of times but eventually, the termination of the VM kills it.

The solution is to add a lock to your code:

```
final Object lock = new Object();

timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() { ... 

   if(stop) { synchronized(lock) { lock.notify(); }} // let test know that we're done
});

synchronized(lock) { lock.wait(); } // wait for timer to finish
```

That said, it's probably futile to test how many keypresses your code can process per second. The hardware, OS and human hands put a limit of about 215 words per minute.

Most often, the code doesn't care how fast it's being called but how often (memory leaks). So you can probably change your code to just loop over the key sequence and simply call `snake.board.getKeyListeners()` without a background thread (which, incidentally, will also give you hundreds of thousands of invocations per second).

Comment: Thank You!! Perfect explanation.